# Cleanest way to count common elements by nested array pairs

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have two nested arrays:

```
one = [
  ["Hiking", "fishing", "photography"], 
  ["The Avengers", "The Dark Knight", "Lord of the Rings"], 
  ["Firefly", "Battlestar Galactica", "The Expanse"], 
  ["The Hobbit", "1984", "Dune", "Ender's Game"]
]
two = [
  ["Hiking", "photography"], 
  ["Whiplash", "Pulp Ficiton", "The Avengers"], 
  ["Firefly", "Battlestar Galactica", "The Expanse"], 
  ["The Hobbit", "1984", "Dune", "Ender's Game"]
]
```

I guess I can iterate and compare one by one, but is there a better way?

Comment: Do they have to be on the same index? For example, if `"1984"` was in the first and not the last array in `two`, would that still be a match?

Comment: Note, that result of comparing nested elements one-by-one can be different from comparing just all arrays elements.

Comment: _"For these two, count would be 10"_ – why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solution (assuming you want to find common elements by arrays pairs):

```
one.zip(two).flat_map { |f, s| f & s }.count
#=> 10
```

Comment: It seems like I guessed correctly, but the question isn't clear itself: you did not say anything about nested elements order. You can use my solution for your own goals, but now @spickerman's answer looks better according to the current question requirements.

Answer (score 4):

I would do something like:

```
(one.flatten & two.flatten).size
#=> 10
```

Comment: If `one[0] << "Whiplash"`, `11` is returned. If that is correct it becomes difficult to interpret what is meant by "nested array pairs" in the title.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the following to avoid the creation of the temporary array `one.zip(two)`.

```
one.size.times.reduce(0) { |t,i| t + (one[i] & two[i]).size }
  #=> 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one more way to skin a cat

```
one.each_with_index.inject(0){|memo,(a,i)| memo += (a & two[i]).size }
#=> 10
```